# In the card game Do-Over Deluxe, can a Take That! card override another Take That?

Tags: do-over

I'm talking about the special edition set [here](https://www.toyco.co.nz/games/board-games/kids-6/do-over-deluxe-game-tin-689623003003).

In this set of *Do-Over*, there are cards called "Take That!". These cards force your opponent to take the current discard pile and add it to their hand. RAW, can a "Take That!" card override another "Take That!"?

Comment: I see Haywire games has the original version rules on their website. Do you have the deluxe rules with your set?

Comment: No, we lost them. That’s why I’m asking.

Comment: Thought so, I've sent a request to Haywire Games for the Deluxe rules. Will let you know if I hear back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Direct Answer:

Yes, a "Take That!" card can be played on top of another "Take That!" card. A "Bomb" card can also be used to defend against a "Take That!" card. Relevant rules snippet:

> **Take That Card** - When this card is played, the next player going clockwise must take the entire discard pile and place it in their hand! However, you can defend against this! If you also have a Take That Card you can play it and force the next player going clockwise to take the discard pile. If playing with two players, you send the discard pile back to the player. A Bomb Card can also be used to obliterate the discard pile during a Take That and no one has to take the discard pile; it is placed to the side.

### Full Rules:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This answered my question and also corrrcted a bunch of rules misunderstandings my family has always played with.

Comment: Haha, happy to help, figured since you lost them, I would include the full rules in the answer. =)